# How is the array that skimage/opencv contour gives is ordered?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I understand that contour finding gives you the x,y coordinates of the points that form the contour. What I want to know is if the points are ordered in such a way that it will give you the solution for a Traveling Salesman Algorithm on said points too.
   Let's say that the coordinates are in list as in so:

```
contours = [(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x2,y2), ... , (xn,yn)]
```

If i draw a line between contours[0] and contours[1], contours[1] and contours[2] , and so on until i draw a line from contours[n] to contours[0] will this plot out my contour ?

Comment: Yes, the points are ordered.

Comment: Just to be sure, in the exact way I said above ? And is it that way for both skimage and opencv or just one of them ?

Comment: @BushLee you can always test it

Comment: @BushLee I am sure about OpenCV

Comment: Wasn't sure how to test it that's why i asked